# Firebase doesn't return user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have an AuthService class that interacts with Firebase. and then in Signin.dart I want to get that user but every time I have a problem getting the user. I get the Error which shows Firebase can't send the user .

Error:

> Exception has occurred. PlatformException
> (PlatformException(firebase_auth,
> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.
> [           Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1
>
> *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7%
> auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* >
> body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px
> no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0
> 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a
> img{border:0}@media screen and
> (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
> no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and
> (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
> no-repeat 0% 0%/100%
> 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
> 0}}@media only screen and
> (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png)
> no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100%
> 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
>
> **403.** That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not
> have permission to get URL
> `/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser` from this
> server.  That’s all we know. ], {}, null))

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = userCredential.user;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign in with email and password

  // register with email and password

  // sign out

}
```

SignIn.dart

```
import 'package:auth_flutter_coffe/Services/Auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SignIn"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[900],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 50.0),
        child: RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () async {
              dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
              if (result == null) {
                print("You Have to be SignIn");
              } else {
                print("SignIn");
                print(result);
              }
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.transit_enterexit),
            label: Text("SignIn")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you  properly connected firbase to your flutter project?

Comment: Yes, It is not first time i am doing this. So cofused

Answer (score 0):

Check the id of your project in `google-service.json` and `build.gradle` file must be same.

Comment: I don't know why, After an hour it worked without any changes 